# Telnet automation / scripting

Tags: python, windows, scripting, automation, telnet

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709801/creating-a-script-for-a-telnet-session) but could not find what I'm looking for.  I am running Windows (the client), and the server is a legacy mainframe type server.

Basically I need to write a script, python code or whatever, to send some know commands to the server via telnet, and preferable capture the output.  Then return when done.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a [python library for telnet](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) connections that reads and writes from/to a telnet connection.

Check the link. It has some basic examples of what you are looking for.

Here's an example from the link:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

It connects to a telnet server. Sends your login credentials and then executes the unix command `ls`. Then  exits the session and prints all output from the telnet server.

Comment: Just a note that on my server, I needed to add a `\r` instead of the `\n`.  Took me a while to debug that.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider [Exscript](http://wiki.github.com/knipknap/exscript/) as well. It simplifies some of the easy tasks but for more complicated there is additional level of abstraction (Exscript is a scripting language in itself). Either way - worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it myself, but maybe [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) is what you need?

> "Pexpect can be used for automating
>   interactive applications such as ssh,
>   ftp, passwd, telnet, etc."

Comment: PExpect does not run on Windows clients.  It gives an error that it needs a UNIX like system.

Comment: I should read the questions more carefully, sorry! :)