# Android - scripting telnet session for sending GPS tracks

Tags: android, geolocation, telnet

All,

I am familiar with the ability to fake GPS information to the emulator through the use of the `geo fix long lat altitude` command when connected through the emulator.

What I'd like to do is have a simulation running on potentially a different computer produce lat, long, altitudes that should be sent over to the Android device to fake the emulator into thinking it has received a GPS update.

I see various solutions for [scripting a telnet session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709801/creating-a-script-for-a-telnet-session); it seems like the best solution is, in pseudocode:

```
while true:
    if position update generated / received
        open subprocess and call "echo 'geo fix lon lat altitude' | nc localhost 5554"
```

This seems like a big hack, although it works on Mac (not on Windows).  Is there a better way to do this?  (I cannot generate the tracks ahead of time and feed them in as a route; the Android system is part of a real time simulation, but as it's running on an emulator there is no position updates.  Another system is responsible for calculating these position updates).

edit:
Alternative method, perhaps more clean, is to use the telnetlib library of python.

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("localhost",5554)
while True:
    if position update generated / received
        tn.write("geo fix longitude latitude altitude\r\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is close to what you're looking for

https://github.com/xperimental/fakegps

Answer (score 1):

Netcat (the nc in the above example) compiles for just about anything, including windows and android itself.

In short, that doesn't look like a hack of a solution, it looks like a very traditional unix scripting style solution that could be easily made to work on any modern platform.

If you don't like opening a new connection for each fix, you should be able to just write a program that generates fixes to standard output and pipe it into netcat.

Comment: Netcat is just great for things like this - beside the while(true) loop is roasting the CPU - sure on a phone nobody might care, but still.

Comment: The while loop almost definitely includes a timed pacing of updates, likely that is done with a callback, blocking I/O or sleep mechanism.  Though ultimately this was about a testing system, not one that would need to be interactively usable or battery powered.