# How to automate interactive telnet commands?

Tags: automation, telnet

I would like to query a telnet server on port 105. What I have to do currently is start an interactive session and enter the commands later one by one.

Since I already know the commands, I would like to automate this process and fetch the results without any manual intervention.

When I try to use pipe to push commands at the time of logging in, this doesn't work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for a tool like [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not say what OS you use, and what kind of script language you want to use I will just provide a few suggestions for further reading.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709801/creating-a-script-for-a-telnet-session) questions might answer what you are looking for.

Also I found [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/19165-how-use-telnet-script.html) that could help you out a bit.