# Telent and command in a single line

Tags: telnet

I have an instrument  and I can `telnet` it to using `telent 192.168.100.2 2000` from `cmd` window. This will open up a terminal and I can give commands to the instrument. For example, a command like `"/tgc/rf/tx1 set gain_target -2.0"`. This works fine. Is there a way I can  give these together in a single step; something like this :

```
telent 192.168.100.2 2000 /tgc/rf/tx1 set gain_target -2.0.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate interactive telnet commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340530/how-to-automate-interactive-telnet-commands)

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `rsh` (**R**emote **SH**ell) command either in linux or windows.

The remote shell (`rsh`) is a command line computer program that can execute shell commands as another user, and on another computer across a computer network.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to activate the RSH with WinRM quickconfig from cmd. It is get denied saying that there a some public networks on my computer. Don't know how to fix it.