# Telnet Shell script

Tags: shell, telnet

I am connecting to a Denon DN-700H network Audio player over IP and have managed to change stations using the following commands in OS X Terminal:

```
telnet
telnet 10.22.71.11
```

which connects successfully, then I see this output:

```
Trying 10.22.71.11...
Connected to 10.22.71.11.
Escape character is '^]'.
BridgeCo AG Telnet server
```

I then input the following to change to a specific Favourite station:

```
FV 01
```

which works, changing the Favourite on the DN-700H. The output shows:

```
NSE2Now Playing
NSE2106 Jack FM Hertfordshire
NSE2106 Jack FM Hertfordshire
NSE8  000:01     100%
```

My question is... how can I script this process? I have succesfully made the connection using the script below, but am failing to actually issue commands to the unit after that. Here is the script I have created so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

telnet 10.22.71.11
sleep 2
send "FV 02"
```

Any tips on recreating what I have achieved by interacting in Terminal as a script would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of:

[automating telnet session using bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts)

[Creating a script for a Telnet session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709801/creating-a-script-for-a-telnet-session)

My suggestion: if you just want to run commands without reading the resulting values, then pass an input file to telnet:

```
$ { echo FV 02; sleep 5; } | telnet 10.22.71.11
```

Comment: is there any way that one can get the output from telnet screen?

Comment: @th3pirat3 you should use "expect" for that or write your own communication program.