# Telnet based check_mk check

Tags: monitoring, telnet, check-mk

I use Chek MK and would like to run a check on device that supports only telnet protocol.
Im new at writing this so would appriciate any help.

Basicly its like this:
I log in via telnet to IP / Port (no username and password) and then issue a command:
"get pw"

I get 3 lines response (first repeat of command, than one empty and in 3rd line actual value:
So output for instance is:

"get pw

600W"

I would like to extract only integer 600 from this output and then based on the specified limits (for instance < 100 is warning, < 50W is critical) combine it to output that checkmk agent would understand.

For instance:

0 power=600 OK: All looking fine

...or:

1 power=90 Warning: Power low

2 power=20 Critical: Power critical

(I already checked this: [Telnet based check_mk checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847595/telnet-based-check-mk-checks) SO I understand that I could do this via script that would get executed on a host with checkmk agent installed.
But I would need some extra help to connect everything togehter. :))

Scripting language can be anything that runs on linux (already tried bash, or expect or python...)
Here for isntance is part of teh script that gets me output:

spawn telnet host port
set timeout 1
send "get pw\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"

Thanks for your help in advance and br, David

Answer (score 0):

problemy solved. Found a great guide how to made it via bash.
Here if anyone else is interested: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/local-check-mk
Br, David